# Importing Map Keys By Interface

Tags: java, class, oop, dictionary, interface

Let's say I have a class with a hashmap data structure:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

public abstract class Data {
    protected Map<String, By> identifiers = new HashMap<>();

public By getSelector(String key) {
    return identifiers.get(key);
}
}
```

3 subclasses which inherit it:

```
public class DataSpecific1 extends Data {
}

public class DataSpecific2 extends Data implements KeysForDataSpecific23 {
}

public class DataSpecific3 extends Data implements KeysForDataSpecific23 {
}
```

Now I want to define an interface which adds hashmap keys to only 2 of these subclasses:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

public interface KeysForDataSpecific23 {
   identifiers.put("key", By.cssSelector("#something"));
}
```

Obviously, this will cause a compile error since the interface can not inherit from the Data class and the variable identifiers is not defined.

Any way of doing it without redundancy such as adding the put() line in both affected classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, using interfaces.

You can do this, though:

```
public abstract class KeysForDataSpecific23 extends Data {
    protected KeysForDataSpecific23() {
        identifiers.put("key", By.cssSelector("something"));
    }
}

public class DataSpecific2 extends KeysForDataSpecific23 {
}


public class DataSpecific3 extends KeysForDataSpecific23 {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, You have facility in **java 8** to have **default method**  in interface ,

With this you can do as follows:

```
public interface KeysForDataSpecific23 {
 default void setKeys(){
   identifiers.put("key", By.cssSelector("something"));
 }
}
```

default methods can give inception behavior to interfaces.

Comment: I use Java 8 but this still does not work due to "variable cannot be resolved"

Comment: Oh yeah... can you get identifiers somehow  say by static helper methods

Comment: Static methods can't access non-static variables so it would break object oriented programming. I took Isaac's solution even though it's not optimal (no multiple inheritance with classes) but it works.